# Error in configuring SOAP service with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc, soap

I am trying to use SOAP web services with Spring boot. I am able to get it working with Spring MVC application(using web.xml without spring boot) but i am stuck in configuring the same with Spring boot xml free setup.

Below is the code for my sample service i am trying to generate the wsdl for.

```
@WebService(serviceName="AddService", targetNamespace="http://add.sample.net/service/", name="addService", portName="adService")
public class MathOps extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport {

    @WebMethod
    public int add(int a, int b){
        return (a+b);
    }
}
```

My Spring Boot config is as below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected final SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        application.logStartupInfo(true);
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(final ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener());
        servletContext.addListener(new WSServletContextListener());

    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean wsServlet(){
        ServletRegistrationBean wsServletBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(new WSSpringServlet(), "/services");
        return wsServletBean;
    }
}
```

When i hit the URL localhost:8080/services, i get the below error.

**There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/services/**

Seems like for url mapping /services, dispatcherServlet is getting invoked instead of WSSpringServlet from below logs.

**[2015-11-07 10:13:00.314] boot - 500  INFO [localhost-startStop-1] --- ServletRegistrationBean: Mapping servlet: 'WSSpringServlet' to [/services]
[2015-11-07 10:13:00.316] boot - 500  INFO [localhost-startStop-1] --- ServletRegistrationBean: Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
[2015-11-07 10:13:01.405] boot - 500  INFO [main] --- Application: Started Application in 5.642 seconds (JVM running for 5.961)
[2015-11-07 10:13:10.407] boot - 500  INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] --- [/]: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[2015-11-07 10:13:10.408] boot - 500  INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] --- DispatcherServlet: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
[2015-11-07 10:13:10.425] boot - 500  INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] --- DispatcherServlet: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 17 ms**

The web.xml configuration which worke without spring boot is below.

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyTest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyTest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>TestService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSSpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TestService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Please help with this issue.

Comment: Remove the registration of the listeners, and only leave the servlet. You might want to set the `order` property so that it gets registered before the dispatcher servlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally managed to get the services working with Spring Boot :).

The only code missing was importing the XML configuration containing web services binding.

Below is the updated WebService configuration class used for configuring SOAP based services in Spring Boot.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWs
@ImportResource("classpath:/applicationContext.xml")
public class WebServiceConfiguration extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean wsServlet(){
        ServletRegistrationBean wsServletBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(new WSSpringServlet(), "/services/*");
        wsServletBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        //wsServletBean.setInitParameters(initParameters);
        return wsServletBean;
    }
}
```

Also below is the applicationContext.xml placed in classpath.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core" xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"
xsi:schemaLocation=
    "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core
    http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/core.xsd
    http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet
    http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd">

  <wss:binding url="/services/MathService">
    <wss:service><!-- nested bean is of course fine -->
      <ws:service bean="#MathService" />
    </wss:service>
  </wss:binding>

  <wss:binding url="/services/StringService">
    <wss:service><!-- nested bean is of course fine -->
      <ws:service bean="#StringService" />
    </wss:service>
  </wss:binding>

  <!-- this bean implements web service methods -->
  <bean id="MathService" class="com.trial.services.MathOps" />
  <bean id="StringService" class="com.trial.services.StringOps" />
</beans>
```

Hope it helps someone facing similar issue with Spring Boot and SOAP service configuration. :)